# Question about SICP chpt 4.1 : How does (analyze expr) help speed up eval?

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

I'm reading the following section of SICP

http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.7

According to the text, the following transformation of `eval` will improve offers a performance improvement, since an expression that gets evaluated many times will only be analyzed once?

```
(define (eval exp env)
    ((analyze exp) env))
```

Here is an `analyze` function given in the book:

```
(define (analyze-if exp)
(let ((pproc (analyze (if-predicate exp)))
    (cproc (analyze (if-consequent exp)))
        (aproc (analyze (if-alternative exp))))
    (lambda (env)
        (if (true? (pproc env))
            (cproc env)
                (aproc env)))))
```

I don't understand why the book says that `analyze` will only run once. Doesn't the the body of `eval`, which is `((analyze exp) env))` basically say that each time `eval` is called, `analyze` will be called with `exp` as its parameter? This would mean that `analyze` would be called every time `eval` is called.

What's wrong with my understanding? I would appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, every time you call `eval` with program code as a parameter, the syntactic evaluator will be invoked. However, when a function within that code calls another function within that code (or, in the simplest case, it calls itself by recursion), the inner `apply` will get the analyzed expression (which is in the end a lambda function) as an argument, rather than a blob of code which would need to be syntactically analyzed again in order to be executed.

Answer (score 5):

Gintautas' answer is correct, but maybe an example is in order. Suppose you've developed a Scheme dialect that sports a loop construct

```
(do-n-times n expr)
```

with the obvious semantics. Now, when you call the naive `eval` to evaluate a loop that runs ten times

```
(eval '(do-n-times 10 (print 'hello)))
```

then it will analyze the loop body ten times. With the version of `eval` that separates analysis from evaluation, the loop body is `analyze`d once, then evaluated ten times.

The analysis phase returns a procedure, which may or not be fast in your Scheme interpreter. However, it could conceivably do all kinds of optimizations (dead code analysis, [JIT compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) to machine code, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

larsmans's answers is extremely good.

As a complementary answer, one can also view `analyze(environ)` as a curried form of `eval(expr, environ)` where the parameter `expr` has been passed in ahead of time. In SICP, you can read the example code like:

```
(define (analyze-assignment exp)
  (let ((var (assignment-variable exp))
        (vproc (analyze (assignment-value exp))))
    (lambda (env)
      (set-variable-value! var (vproc env) env)
      'ok)))
```

When you see a `let (([var] [preprocessed stuff]))`, that is preprocessing being stored in a closure until it is needed later when `environ` is passed in.